# System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream's Async read callback

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous, networkstream

I'm may be just misunderstanding something fundamental here but...

**Senario:** I call `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`'s `BeginRead` method and my machine receives a response/request from a network device. The runtime runs my callback in its own thread. Before this thread can call `EndRead`, the machine receives another response/request.

**Question:** Will the runtime call my callback in another thread immediately or wait for me to call `EndRead` and then `BeginRead` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run the callback method immediately in another thread. (hence the asynchronous rather than blocking calls).

Comment: Surely this is wrong? There is only 1 callback raised per call to BeginRead() so unless you call BeginRead() again in the callback then you won't read any more data?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call EndRead and then BeginRead again to handle the new incoming message.